# How to Debug Rust Executable with arguments in DAP-mode?

Tags: debugging

I did install [dap-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode) and configured it for Rust as instructed [here](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/rust/README.html) and [there](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/dap-mode/page/configuration/#rust). Although it looks like it is working, I have no idea of how to debug the executable with passed arguments.